# Debugging CakePHP White Screen of Death

Tags: cakephp

I'm new to CakePHP, so I apologize in advance for my lack of knowledge.

I have a custom CakePHP application that works great on my webhosting account.  I've downloaded it to my local machine and I'm trying to get it to run on my WAMP server.  I've set up the database correctly, downloaded all the .htaccess files and turned on the Apache rewrite_module but I still get a white screen of death when I open the site in my browser.

Interestingly the apache error log says `"File does not exist: C:/wamp/www/favicon.ico".`  Of course this file should be in the `c:/www/aplication_name/app/webroot` directory.  So for some reason the application is looking at the `C:/wamp/www/ directory` instead.

The path definitions in `webroot/index.php` are correct, so I don't know where else the problem could be.

I've been debugging this all day, so any help is appreciated.
Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the value of `Configure:read('debug')` (it is set in `config/core.php`)? It should be greater than zero, so you'll get PHP errors displayed. Setting debug to zero is for live environments, in development mode you should use a value of 1, 2 or 3 (every level up means more debug information being shown).

If your debug value is set correctly, try to find out if some setting in Apache / PHP is surpressing the PHP error messages regardless of the debug setting (although I think it's highly unlikely that this will be the case).

Comment: @LEO and @Vindia 
Strangely the php error log wasn't displaying anything.  Thanks a lot for your help.  Setting the Configure:read('debug') to 3 resolved the problem.  I thought I had looked at that before - I guess I was mistaken.  I'd accept both your answers but it only let's me accept one.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I used to get a blank page i.e white screen of death upon login. The reason was I had written $this->autoRender = false; in one of the private functions that gets executed as soon as user logged in.

The way I debugged it:
I created a new app and went on pasting functions one by one and kept on check for white screen after login. As soon as I pasted my private function with autorender false I got the white screen and finally fixed the issue after a days hardwork.

Answer (score 0):

JSo have you configured your virtual host in Apache?

For WAMP in the http-vhosts.conf file add something like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

DocumentRoot "d:/websites/myapp/app/webroot/"
ServerName local.myapp

<Directory "d:/websites/myapp/app/webroot/">
    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then in your windows hosts file i.e. 'C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts' add

```
127.0.0.1    local.myapp
```

Restart Wamp then visiting local.myapp should give you a result.

ADDED-

Do you have display_errors set to 'on' in the php ini file? What does the php error log show you?

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I wasn't aware that I needed a virtual host, but I guess that makes sense.  After lots of fiddling, I finally got the virtual host working properly, however I'm still getting the white screen of death.  I even tried setting the main apache directory  to /app/webroot/.   Now with the virtual host working, it is finding the favicon in the webroot folder. This problem is perplexing because the site works fine on the webhost.

Comment: pyro did you see the addition?

Comment: Leo Vindia, apologies for not getting back to you, I thought I had already responded (I guess it was very late at night).  With your help I finally debugged this.  It turns out I just needed to set the Configure:read('debug') in Cake core.php to 3.  I also thought I had previously already checked this (I guess I wasn't getting much sleep at the time)